# Attempting to make a background image a button that displays # of times clicked by all who visit site

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #background {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;;
            background-size:100% 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fffaee;
}
.eyes{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.eye{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f7f4eb;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ball{
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #333;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="prank, pidgeons, old man, interactive, art, teague, 
    portfolio">
    <meta name="description" content="Frank loves to feed pidgeons on his bench this is where he stays">
        <title>Frank</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="images/favicon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/anim.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="eyes">
    <div class="eye">
      <div class="ball"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="eye">
      <div class="ball"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <img src="images/bird.png" id="background">

<script>
  var balls = document.getElementsByClassName("ball");
  document.onmousemove = function(){
    var x = event.clientX * 100 / window.innerWidth + "%";
    var y = event.clientY * 100 / window.innerHeight + "%";
    //event.clientX => get the horizontal coordinate of the mouse
    //event.clientY => get the Vertical coordinate of the mouse
    //window.innerWidth => get the browser width
    //window.innerHeight => get the browser height

    for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
      balls[i].style.left = x;
      balls[i].style.top = y;
      balls[i].style.transform = "translate(-"+x+",-"+y+")";
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>[bird][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmbdG.png
```

I have an image of a bird as the background of my site id like to be able to make him into a button that would display how many times its been clicked by all visitors of the website is this possible?
If so how should i go about ingratiating it into my site ive tried to add a button to the background photo a few times but had no luck as it kept resizing my image in strange ways

Comment: You will need to store the click count on your server. On click of your button, update the click count on the server. You can  implement an AJAX call, which will update the value on server when someone clicks the button.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of challenges here:
1. Place background image.
2. Make it clickable and increment a counter.
3. Store and retrieve the counter for all visitors.

---

1. The `<img src="">` code will place an image using HTML. This is most commonly used for placing a smaller image in a text block.  Instead, it looks like you might want the entire background of your site to be this image. Try this instead:

```
body{
  background-color: #fffaee;
  background-image: url("images/bird.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

you could also do this whole thing in one line:

```
body{
  background: #ffaee url("images/bird.png") no-repeat 100% 100%;
}
```

---

2. If you want it to be clickable, perhaps use the `<button></button>` tags instead. You'll use javascript to detect the click and increment the counter. Lets use vanilla javascript to do this:

**HTML:**

```
...
<body>
  <button id="birdcounter" onclick="increment()">
    <span id="counter" value=0>
    </span>
  </button>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#birdcounter{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fffaee;
  background-image: url("images/bird.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function increment(){
  var counterElement = document.getElementById("counter");
  var oldValue = counterElement.value;
  var newValue = oldValue + 1;
  counterElement.value = newValue;
  counterElement.innerHTML = newValue;
}
```

Note: This example is verbose for the sake of being clear about what is happening. It could be simplified in a handful of ways.

---

3. Now we need to store the current value somewhere, so future visitors can know how many times the button has be clicked. For this, we need a database and some way to get data into and out of the database.

There are a lot of options, but they are all beyond the scope of this answer. To learn this, you will probably want to do some research into AJAX (a javascript method) and probably MySQL. You might benefit from a HTML preprocessor like PHP. You might also try to learn a Javascript framework like Vue.